# Socket.io rooms is sending to everybody, not just single room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, handlebars.js

I have no idea why this won't work; here's my code:

```
      io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('join', function(data) {
          socket.join(data.email); // We are using room of socket io
            User.findById(bid.highestBidder, (err, theUser) => {
              io.sockets.in(theUser.email).emit('outbid', {msg: 'You have been outbid!'});
            });
        });
      });
```

Now, here's the code on the client-side javascript:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();

  var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();

  socket.emit('join', {
    email: userEmail
  });

  socket.on("outbid", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
</script>
```

If you need me to paste more code, let me know and I will.

Basically, when the socket function gets executed, it's sending it to every browser instead of just the room with the "email."

Comment: Is `theUser.email` valid? Also, `socket.join()` may be async, so you may have to wait (using a callback) before it has actually joined the room.

Comment: ^ could the "highest bidder" be null thus not returning an email and sending out without an argument in your call to `io.sockets.in(null).emit()`

Comment: @Ken, trying to access `email` field in `null` would throw an error. I am, of course, assuming, that OP would tell us about the error.

Comment: @hlfrmn Okay, then maybe the user doesn't have an email address associated with their record, resulting in the same question I originally posed. (the main take away being, check that all the values are being returned properly)

Comment: @Ken, that is what I thought about as well, but hoped that OP would check that. I typically check for simple obvious mistakes in my logic after just an hour of beating my head against the wall. StackOverflow comes at around 5 hours :)

Comment: @hlfrmn When ever the question is coming from someone with rep close to 0, I assume they did virtually nothing to check their code and assume it could be an extremely entry level mistake.

Comment: I know the email has a value on both ends as I've console logged it both client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('room name');
});

io.to('room name').emit('some event');
```

Comment: I'm gonna try it asap and I'll let you know if it worked!

Comment: Some say that after 6 years he is still checking if worked